# Browsing compressed files withtour decompressing them

Tags: c++, unix, archive

I am trying to make a program in C++ that should be able to browse through archives and open a desired file in that archive. Is that possible to be accomplished without decompressing the files (or rather directories) being browsed?
Currently I am doing this to work on Unix operating systems, but the end goal is to work for Windows as well. So the goal is to have something simmilar to how you get a list of files with 'ls' command and navigate through the directories (like cd).
Everything that I found so far can list all the files in a archive (like zipinfo, etc.) though my goal is not to list all the files at once, but be able to brose thorugh the directories. For example if I have something.zip and inside it I have 2 folders - folder1 and folder2, and inside them they have 2 files each - file1 and file2 and folder1, and file4 and file4 in folder2.
With zipinfo I will get something like that:
folder1/file1
folder1/file2
folder2/file3
folder2/file4

and I want to see only this:
folder1
folder2

and from there be able to navigate into each folder. For example go into folder1 and see:
file1
file2

How can this be acomplished using C++? If seeing only folders is not possible I will be happy with some tool with which I can see all the files and I can parse them in a way to make only folders appear and make the "browsing" functionality.

EDIT: I need it to work with as most as possible methods of compression.

Comment: I feel like there are people here only to downvote questions without any reason at all.

Comment: There are several issues with the question. You did not state which [compression method(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats) you are using for starters. Then, you ask if it is possible in C++. Well, the answer to that is YES. I am not aware of a compression method without an accompanying C library. You may or may not have a header structure that provides a table of contents to help with disk layout. It depends on the compression method.

Comment: @jww sure, I rewrote that, I don't see the reason for the pedantic behaviour. As to the compressions method it should be able to work with as most methods as possible

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a C++ solution, but if you have access to `zipinfo` and run the following command:

```
zipinfo -1 filename.zip
```

This will give you output formatted like this:

```
file.txt
another.txt
directory/another/file.txt
yetagain.odt
another/file.png
directory/file.txt
```

By parsing this output, you can create a structure like this:

```
+-- file.txt
+-- another.txt
+--\directory
|   +--\another
|   |   +-- file.txt
|   +-- file.txt
+--\another
|   +-- file.png
```

You can then allow the user to browse this tree as you want them to be able to.

Comment: Yes, this was my idea, for the parsing as well, but I need to be able to do it in a c++ code

Comment: @BorisDishov Ok. Well, show us what you've got so far and I can help you with it. You could look at how `zipinfo` implements it, and perhaps link to ("borrow" code from) `zipinfo` since it's Open Source.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tar -t` you can look at the filenames of the compressed files, without really untarring them, see man pages:

```
TAR(1)                                                                       
...
NAME
     tar — The GNU version of the tar archiving utility

SYNOPSIS
     tar [-] A --catenate --concatenate | c --create | d --diff --compare | --delete | r --append | t --list | --test-label | u --update | x --extract --get [options] [pathname ...]

FUNCTION LETTERS
     Main operation mode:

     -t, --list
           list the contents of an archive
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I am looking for a way to that in my code, not from the command line.

Comment: `system("tar", "-t", "...");`? I haven't had to do `c` coding in a long time, but you can definitely call existing programs from inside your program. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I know I can do system calls that way, but I don't want to do that as it is slow (or I suspect it is slow). I would be glad to be proved wrong so I can just to the easy approach.

Comment: given the size of the task you're proposing, I can't see how a `system` call is going to impact the overall time of individual task execution (and should save you a lot of time on coding the project). Wouldn't it be better to get something working and then optimize it if slow reaction time is really a problem? ;-)  Good luck!